# Why wasn't Jiraya reincarnated?

Tags: naruto

Most of the villains to most of the kages were reincarnated but Why wasn't Jiraya reincarnated.

Kabuto reincarnated almost everyone from the past during the war and the presence of Jiraya could've been too helpful for him.But my question is what was the reason for reincarnating him.

Answer (score 2):

Reincarnation done the way Kabuto chose to do it requires the body of the person being reincarnated and a host body. This is told to the third hokage by Orochimaru in the Naruto series.

Jiraiya dies while fighting pain and sinks to the bottom of the ocean. Since his body was never preserved and buried, Kabuto could not revive him along with the others.